# Как транспонировать результаты sql-запроса

Tags: sql, запрос

Есть таблица T:

```
id    value
2      a
3      a
4      b
5      c
```

Необходимо сформировать запрос, который бы вернул следующий набор:

```
a b c
2 1 1
```

Если написать такой запрос:

```
SELECT value, Count(value)
FROM T
Group by value
```

то получатся результаты:

```
a 2
b 1
c 1
```

А вопрос заключается в том как этот результат повернуть, либо как написать правильный запрос. Ковырялся с UNION и с PIVOT не получилось.

Comment: Подозреваю, что это гораздо труднее, чем кажется с первым взглядом.

Comment: используете mysql?

Comment: Тестовое задание на позицию Junior Developer. Видимо подразумевается независимость от субд. Остальные задачи были простыми. Я использую Firebird и MS.

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/14609

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Ответ на англ, будет полезно: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Comment: Посещал. Думал, может проще все

Answer (score 2):

Используйте CASE или PIVOT. [Здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_pivot.html), фактически, ваш случай.

Answer (score 1):

при помощи интернета и какой-то... получилось такое. Это только для MySQL, как я понимаю,  из-за group_concat. Но, может, чем поможет

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (id int, value char(1));
insert into t1 values 
(2, 'a'),
(3, 'a'),
(4, 'b'),
(5, 'c');
select group_concat(if(v='a', c, null)) a, 
       group_concat(if(v='b', c, null)) b, 
       group_concat(if(v='c', c, null)) c
  from (select value v, Count(value) c
          from t1
        group by value ) temp

a  b  c
2  1  1
```

Comment: да, group_concat в ms sql нету. Читал про него когда гуглил решение.

Answer (score 1):

Не претендую на изящность решения, но вот вариант с курсором:

```
DECLARE @T2 table (id int, value char(1))
INSERT INTO @T2 values (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'c')

DECLARE @vals varchar(10)
DECLARE @cnts varchar(10)
DECLARE @v char(1)
DECLARE @c int

DECLARE @cur cursor
SET @cur = cursor local for
  SELECT value, COUNT(value)
  FROM @T2
  GROUP BY value

OPEN @cur
FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @v, @c
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF @vals IS NULL
    SET @vals = @v
  ELSE
    SET @vals = @vals + ' ' + @v
  IF @cnts IS NULL
    SET @cnts = CAST(@c as varchar(10))
  ELSE
    SET @cnts = @cnts + ' ' + CAST(@c as varchar(10))
  FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @v, @c
END
CLOSE @cur
DEALLOCATE @cur
-- ну и собственно результат:
SELECT @vals
SELECT @cnts
```